# Python: how to declare a list start with 1 and interval 4, 100 elements?

Tags: python, list, declaration, intervals

I wish to have a list like this:

```
[1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,37,…]
```

> (1) How to quickly declare it?
>
> (2) How to do it with “yield”?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range

Comment: You can use `list(range(1,401,4))`. range returns a generator, but you can write your own generator by using `yield`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: how to calculate a summary of a list without creating this whole list first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059247/python-how-to-calculate-a-summary-of-a-list-without-creating-this-whole-list-fi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you can try this:

```
def generate_list(size, interval):
    flag = 0
    number = 0
    while True:
        if flag >= size:
            break
        number += 1
        if number % interval == 1:
            flag += 1
            yield number


def print_list():
    for i in generate_list(100, 4):
        print i


print_list()
```

if you don't wanna use key word `yield`, you can use this line program:

```
print list(range(1,401,4))
```